# Declare an interface that a struct conforms to

Tags: c#, interface, struct

I need a PointF-like struct in PCL code.  But System.Drawing is not available.  So I declare my own struct:

```
public struct PointFF: IPointF {
  public float X { get; set; };
  public float Y { get; set; };
}
```

Now I want to define an interface IPointF that both PointF and PointFF conform to:

```
interface IPointF {
  float X {get; set; };
  float Y {get; set; };
}
```

Lastly, I want to somehow "make it official" that PointF conforms to IPointF, so I can do things like this:

```
public void DoFunkyStuff (IPointF p) {
  float x = p.X;
  float y = p.Y;
  // do something with x and y
}
```

Is that possible?

Comment: Why are you using a `struct` in this instance? It will be boxed .. you may as well use a class.

Comment: Simon right. It will work, but for every cast from struct to interface it will do boxing, and create copy of that structure in heap. so it will waste some memory each time.

Comment: I'm new to all of this.  I'm fine with doing it without the interface if that would create problems.  But I'm still thinking the struct could be the way to go, so I can cast PointF to PointFF and vice versa.  Or is that dangerous?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it's no possible for you do to what you want.

In general, though it is *possible* for structures to implement interfaces, it's considered a very bad idea. It forces your structures to be boxed, and tends to break the value-type semantics you expect from a structure. But the language permits it, so that's not your main problem.

What you can't do is to somehow arrange from a pre-existing structure to implement that interface without changing it's source code. Since you have no control over `System.Drawing.PointF`, there's nothing you can do to convince the compiler that it implements your `IPointF`.

Comment: ..I can't imagine the horror people would create with a feature like "extension interface implementations". +1

Comment: @Simon Other languages (e.g. Go) use it to great effect. I don’t see how it qualifies as “horror”.

Comment: Does Go have "extension interface implementation"? I thought it just let any object with the same methods sub in for another object. Not quite what the OP is saying here I don't think.